# Is it possible to use the Webmail helper without hardcoding the SMTP information?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am considering using the [WebMail helper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webmail.aspx) for sending email.

Is there any way to provide the SMTP information without hard-coding them into the application?

Comment: You can make your own in 10 minutes. This one doesn't even have async sending option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, you can use web.config entries, and then access those config entries in your application.

For example:

```
WebMail.SmtpServer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpServerToUse"];
```